# Not Able to Select a Range in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro in a sheet "A" ,

on change in  sheet A , i want to copy a range from sheet "C" and paste in sheet "D"

This flow is fine ,and I am able to acheive it . The problem is when I am trying to select the range in sheet B.

```
rownum= 83 (I get it dynamically)

colnum = 31 (Number of columns in rownum)
```

Now I want to copy the 83rd Row till 31st column.

Problem Begins :

```
 Sheets("B").Range("A83:AO83").Select   ~ works like Charm
```

As the above is not dynamic ,I want to use

```
Sheets("B").Range(Cells(rownum,1),Cells(rownum,colnum)).Select  ~ Object Defined Error
```

Any Ideas !!! I am stuck like for 2 hrs.. its not happening .

This is some part of code , to cause less confusion , I am not posting all the code , The code stops at the last line !! OBJECT DEFINED ERROR .

```
Dim rownum As Integer
   Dim colnum As Integer

 rownum = Application.Match(searchFE, Sheets("Attendance").Range("D:D"), 0)
 colnum = Cells(rownum, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Sheets("Attendance").Range(Cells(rownum, 1), Cells(rownum, colnum)).Select
```

both  rownum and colnum are getting values .

Comment: But you do not need to select it. You can directly perform the operation on that range. You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Your code is working fine in my computer... it returns the error when colnum or rownum are not defined first.

Comment: it is defined , let me see , if  I can paste more code here

Comment: @Balinti Pleae Check

Comment: Run it in debug mode (pressing f8 when vb screen is open ) and after the first line, point the mouse on rownum (on the code) and see  there is a value.

Comment: YES , there are values for rownum and Colnum

Comment: add before the last row : MsgBox (rownum * 2 / 2 & " " & colnum * 2 / 2)

Comment: Is it showing " 31 83" ?

Comment: @Balinti I am getting 80 and 31 , which is exactly the numbers I require according to the data

Comment: You've got a couple of good answers below that explain the lack of explicitly referencing a parent worksheet but another version of the same would be: `Sheets("B").Range("A" & rownum).Resize(1, colnum)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at

`Sheets("Attendance").Range(Cells(rownum, 1), Cells(rownum, colnum)).Select`

The `Cells(rownum, 1)` is not fully qualified. It is not clearly given from which `Sheet` the `Cells` should be taken. So `ActiveSheet.Cells(rownum, 1)` is assumed. Thats why the above command will fail if `Sheets("Attendance")` is not the active sheet.

```
...
With Sheets("Attendance")
 .Range(.Cells(rownum, 1), .Cells(rownum, colnum)).Select
End With
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is just a matter of `.address`.
When you are selecting your range, you need to give the address as input, so basically your only error was to write:

```
Sheets("B").Range(Cells(rownum,1),Cells(rownum,colnum)).Select
```

Instead of:

```
Sheets("B").Range(Cells(rownum,1).Address(0,0),Cells(rownum,colnum).Address(0,0)).Select
```

I like to write `.address(0,0)` because it reminds me that it is the absolute address (starting from row and col = 0)

I'm also not sure about:

```
Sheets("Attendance").Range(Cells(rownum, 1), Cells(rownum, colnum)).Select
```

Normally I'd write:

```
Worksheets("Attendance").Range(Cells(rownum, 1).address(0,0), Cells(rownum, colnum).address(0,0)).Select
```

And be careful to refer to a specific `Workbook` if you are working with more than one!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get to that last row then use this code

```
    Sub GetThere()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Attendance")

    With sh
        r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        c = .Cells(r, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, c))
    End With

    Application.Goto Reference:=rng

End Sub
```

If you actually want to do something with the range such as copy it to a different location, then use this code.

```
Sub GetThere2()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Attendance")

    With sh
        r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        c = .Cells(r, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, c))
    End With

    rng.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

If you really want to select the range, then you have to make sure the sheet is selected as well.

```
Sub GetThere3()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Attendance")

    With sh
        r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        c = .Cells(r, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, c))
        .Select
    End With

    rng.Select

End Sub
```